# Passing Data vs. Separate Request in AngularJS using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

I'm new to angular and trying to figure out how best to accomplish this.

Say you have set up an ngResource factory to get a bunch of widgets . You return those widgets(`GET /api/widgets`) and display them on the page in a list.

Now say you can edit those widgets in a dialog box by clicking an edit button next to the object in the list. Is it better practice to pass the individual widget's data (that was already retrieved by the first `$resource` call) to the edit dialog, or simply pass an ID parameter to the dialog box and have it resolve it's own `$resource` call using a separate `GET /api/widgets/:widgetID` call.

The data wouldn't realistically change between loading the list and clicking the edit button, so it doesn't need to be synced to the exact second. Both of these requests would come from the same factory, but the question is if you should store the data and pass it, or execute a separate request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason to fetch it again, I would just reuse the object.

Comment: The reason I asked is I was under the impression that angular modules/etc should be independent of each other. In this case, the modal would be dependent on the parent to send it an object. Is that alright?

Comment: Is your routing / state management setup so that a user could get to the modal without first going to the parent?  If so then it might be more straightforward to just retrieve it from the modal.  If not, then passing the existing object makes sense.

Comment: nope, they could only get to the modal by clicking on an "edit" button. Not by /api/widgets/:widgetID/edit. So I guess it works. Awesome, thanks!